# html + phaser code and file not getting read

Tags: javascript, html, express, phaser-framework

I been trying to get my project to display on a server but for some reason it wont recognize my js file at all.

Ive tried using live server extension on vscode, http-server to run my server and serving it to express and nothing has been working Im not sure if its the code or just my file structure.

ive been getting just a white screen and this error in the console

game.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/game.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

and in the html it says basically it cant find the game.js file

how do i fix my code to display the game.js correctly heres my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Phaser Game</title>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.24.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

ive tried src ./js, just js/ and it shows the file when i command click but it doesnt render on the page
i also tried to put the game.js code in my html in the body instead of the head but it still doesnt work

game.js

```
//create scene
let gameScene = new Phaser.Scene('Game');

// load assets
gameScene.preload = function(){
    //load images
    this.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('dragon', 'assets/dragon.png');
    this.load.image('treasure', 'assets/treasure.png');

};

//once after the preload ends
gameScene.create = function(){
    //create background sprite
    this.add.sprite(0,0, 'background');
};

//set configuration of the game
let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO, //phaser will use webgl if available but if not it will use canvas
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    scene: gameScene,
};

//create new game, pass the configuration
let game = new Phaser.Game('config');
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

this is how my file structure is

```
-assets
-js
   -game.js
   -phaser.js
-index.html
-server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message shows that the `game.js` file is loaded *"...game.js:1 Failed to load resource: t..."*. The issue seems to be that the ***assets*** *(images)* cannot be loaded.

If you look at the `server.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

the `assets` folder needs to be inside of the `public` folder *([link to the documenation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html))*.

So the file structure would have to look something like this:

```
-public
   -asstes
-js
   -game.js
   -phaser.js
-index.html
-server.js
```

*Or you change the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` line, to something more suitable.*

> **Tipp:** In the browser developer tools, on the **network** tab you can see which files are not loaded / not found.